# Grouping nested arrays and transforming to hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a nested array:

```
array = [
  [8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1],
  [4321, 62770, 2.0, 603.24], 
  [4321, 105191, 2.0, 1900.8],
  [1234, 62770, 2.0, 603.24]
]
```

The element at index `0` in each subarray is the `sales_user`, and I wanted to group by that. I need to get it to:

```
[
  [8765, [105191, 2.0, 1582.1]]
  [[4321, [[62770, 2.0, 603.24]], [[105191, 2.0, 1900.8]]]
  [1234, [[62770, 2.0, 603.24]]]
]
```

I tried doing this:

```
array.group_by(&:first).map { |c, xs| [c, xs] }
```

It almost gave me what I wanted:

```
[
  [8765, [[8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]]], 
  [4321, [[4321, 62770, 2.0, 603.24]] [4321, 105191, 2.0, 1900.8]]],
  [1234, [[1234, 62770, 2.0, 603.24]]]
]
```

but it included the `sales_user` in the subarrays.

I would like to transform the grouped array to a hash as well. Is this easily possible? Maybe I need to convert the original array into a hash and then do the group by `sales_user`.

Comment: It's really unclear what output you want. Your brackets don't seem to match up and your commas aren't consistent. Please edit your question to be easier to read. Ideally the expected output in your question should be valid Ruby code that we can directly compare our own results to.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.map{| e | { e.first => e.drop(1) }}
=> [{8765=>[105191, 2.0, 1582.1]}, 
    {4321=>[62770, 2.0, 603.24]}, 
    {4321=>[105191, 2.0, 1900.8]}, 
    {1234=>[62770, 2.0, 603.24]}]
```

I suggest doing this:

```
keys = [ :sales_user, :user_id, :month, :amount]
array.map{|r | r.map.with_index{| e,i | { keys[ i ] => e }}.reduce :merge }
=> [{:sales_user=>8765, :user_id=>105191, :month=>2.0, :amount=>1582.1}, 
    {:sales_user=>4321, :user_id=>62770, :month=>2.0, :amount=>603.24},
    {:sales_user=>4321, :user_id=>105191, :month=>2.0, :amount=>1900.8}, 
    {:sales_user=>1234, :user_id=>62770, :month=>2.0, :amount=>603.24}]
```

Comment: I'm still left with an array :/ Is there a way have the inner array as a hash as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
array.group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k, v.size==1 ? v.first : v] }
  #=> [[8765, [8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]],
  #    [4321, [[4321, 62770, 2.0, 603.24], [4321, 105191, 2.0, 1900.8]]],
  #    [1234, [1234, 62770, 2.0, 603.24]]]
```

The steps:

```
h = array.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {8765=>[[8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]],
  #    4321=>[[4321, 62770, 2.0, 603.24], [4321, 105191, 2.0, 1900.8]],
  #    1234=>[[1234, 62770, 2.0, 603.24]]}

enum = h.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: {8765=>[[8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]],
  #                  4321=>[[4321, 62770, 2.0, 603.24], [4321, 105191, 2.0, 1900.8]],
  #                  1234=>[[1234, 62770, 2.0, 603.24]]}:map> 

 k,v = enum.next
   #=> [8765, [[8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]]] 
 k #=> 8765 
 v #=> [[8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]] 
 [k, v.size==1 ? v.first : v]
   #=> [8765, [[8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]].size==1 ?
   #=>   [[8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]].first : [[8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]]]
   #=> [8765, true ? [8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1] : [[8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]]]          
   #=> [8765, [8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1]] 

 k,v = enum.next
   #=> [4321, [[4321, 62770, 2.0, 603.24], [4321, 105191, 2.0, 1900.8]]] 
 k #=> 4321 
 v #=> [[4321, 62770, 2.0, 603.24], [4321, 105191, 2.0, 1900.8]] 
 [k, v.size==1 ? v.first : v]
   #=> [4321, [[4321, 62770, 2.0, 603.24], [4321, 105191, 2.0, 1900.8]]] 

 k,v = enum.next
   #=> [1234, [[1234, 62770, 2.0, 603.24]]] 
 k #=> 1234 
 v #=> [[1234, 62770, 2.0, 603.24]] 
 [k, v.size==1 ? v.first : v]
   #=> [1234, [1234, 62770, 2.0, 603.24]] 

 k,v = enum.next
   #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. Is this what you want?

```
arrays = [ [ 8765, 105191, 2.0, 1582.1  ],
           [ 4321,  62770, 2.0,  603.24 ], 
           [ 4321, 105191, 2.0, 1900.8  ],
           [ 1234,  62770, 2.0,  603.24 ] ]

p arrays.group_by(&:shift)
# => { 8765 => [ [ 105191, 2.0, 1582.1  ] ],
#      4321 => [ [  62770, 2.0,  603.24 ],
#                [ 105191, 2.0, 1900.8  ] ],
#      1234 => [ [  62770, 2.0,  603.24 ] ]
#    }
```

**Note:** The above will modify your original arrays. If that's a problem, `dup` them first:

```
arrays.map(&:dup).group_by(&:shift)
```

Or how about this?

```
keys = %w[ sales_user user_id month amount ]

p arrays.map {|values| keys.zip(values).to_h }
    .group_by {|hsh| hsh.delete("sales_user") }
# => { 8765 => [ { "user_id" => 105191, "month" => 2.0, "amount" => 1582.1  } ],
#      4321 => [ { "user_id" =>  62770, "month" => 2.0, "amount" =>  603.24 },
#                { "user_id" => 105191, "month" => 2.0, "amount" => 1900.8  } ],
#      1234 => [ { "user_id" =>  62770, "month" => 2.0, "amount" =>. 603.24 } ]
#    }
```